# WordPress 3.6 query by post format not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm using IFTTT to post Instagram photos to my blog as Image post format posts. I want to just display the most recent Image post.

This code should be working, but is displaying all three posts on my blog (it's new, there are 2 standard posts and 1 image post).

```
        <?php $latest_instagram = get_posts( array(
        'showposts' => 1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => 'post-format-image',
              'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ) ); ?>
    <?php $instagram = new WP_Query($latest_instagram); ?>
    <?php while ($instagram->have_posts()) : $instagram->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Everything I've looked up suggest this is the way to go. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify that post_format is a custom taxonomy and not a custom post type? Also, have you tried changing post-format-image to post_format_image? Doubt that this is the problem, but I'm not sure how IFTTT works. At least in one case - using Elasticsearch with Wordpress - it's necessary to use underscores rather than hyphens for naming taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing showposts with posts_per_page

//Edit
Just noticed you are using get_posts then passing it into a query. remove get_posts() function and you should be good!

```
    <?php $latest_instagram = array(
    'showposts' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'post-format-image',
          'operator' => 'IN'
        )
      )
    ); ?>
<?php $instagram = new WP_Query($latest_instagram); ?>
<?php while ($instagram->have_posts()) : $instagram->the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no difference.